# Weird width of app window causing undesirable margin

Tags: android, css, cordova

So I'm making an app for android 2.1 using phonegap and there is some extra blank margin on the right side (about 5px) that makes the page horizontally scrollable (I really want to avoid that).
I went crazy changing and testing css until I tried to check widths with javascript.
(device is 320px wide)

main div is 320px, body is 320px and document is 320px... but window is 325px!

I'm blaming it all on this window weird width, but I don't really know what to do...
I guess this is some kind of bug (since everything runs fine on 2.2). But is there a workaround? Is someone experiencing this too? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to provide some code for us to work with!

Answer (score 1):

It's hard without code, but I had the exact same problem and solved it with:

```
body {
margin: 0px;
}
```

Maybe padding too. Check your page in a browser like Chrome and check the metrics of the body or any other elements that might cause problems.

Comment: already tried that, no difference... and it's fine on and 2.2, chrome and firefox (on mac)

Comment: it's very weird, but I've found a solution... going to post it. thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

problem solved, although it doesn't make much sense...

my "main div" (which covers all the page) had this css rules:

```
.main-div{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

it seems that there is some kind of calculating issue with this positioning in android 2.1 that makes it larger than it is meant to be.
after changing the positioning from "absolute" to "fixed", it becomes fit with the screen, no right margin.
it may be a bad fix for one who needs to use the absolute positioning, but it's fine for my case.

i hope this helps someone someday ;)